# chmod +x cant find build.sh file

Tags: bash

I have been trying to make a VCS in C++ but the build file is not running in my LINUX(Ubuntu).
It is prompting the above message.

my build file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
udo apt-get install openssl -y

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev -y

mkdir -p ~/imperium/bin

cp imperium.sh ~/imperium

cd ..

make

cd ~/imperium/bin || echo "error"

chmod +x main

cd ..

if grep -q "source $PWD/imperium.sh" "$PWD/../.bashrc" ; then

    echo 'already installed bash source';

else

    echo "source $PWD/imperium.sh" >> ~/.bashrc;

fi

my imperium.sh file is also as follows:
function imperium(){

DIR=$PWD

export dir=$DIR

cd ~/imperium/bin || echo "Error"

./main "$@"

cd "$DIR" || echo "Error"

}
```

I will be heavily obliged if any one can solve this problem of mine. After chmod I have been doing:

./build.sh but its prompting that build.sh file does not exists.

Comment: Use pwd and is. Is the the file script in your current working directory?

Comment: Please show the **exact** run log, including error msgs.

Comment: after #!/bin/bash add `set -x; set -e` - this adds debug output and exits on errors. Execution will stop the moment an error is encountered. This gives you a log of what happened and stops when something fails so you can see what happened

Answer (score 0):

1. For me it seems you have a typo right in the 3rd row "udo" ->
   "sudo".
2. Also, You should avoid using cd .. and use relative paths for
   the commands.